# Javascript doesn't load PHP function in codeigniter, but does in pure PHP environment

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I have this `file.html` that tries to call a `neg.php` when the image is clicked (there are many `<p class="bagi">`.

```
<p class ="bagi">           
    <a href="try.html" onclick="return false;">                        
       <img src="images/neg.png" title ="Rate this negative" onclick="negative(this);">
       Try try try try try
    </a>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function negative(obj) {
       var url = obj.parentNode.valueOf('href');
       var name = obj.parentNode.innerText;
       alert(url);
       $("#quote p").load("neg.php?url="+ url + "&name=" + name);
    }
</script>

<div id="quote"><p></p></div>
```

The `neg.php`, which is located in the same folder as the code above, and will write a text file into a subfolder `cat/nonstatistics`, is like this:

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
$url = $_GET["url"];
$name = $_GET["name"];

$file = 'cat/nonstatistics/' . $name . '.txt';
if (!file_exists($file)) {
    include_once 'classifier/classifier.php';
    include_once 'classifier/trainer.php';

    $current = file_get_contents($url);
    $current2 = strip_tags($current);

    $tr = new trainer();//I use PHP text classifier in this
    $arr = array('statistika', 'nonstatistika');
    $tr->makeCategory($arr);
    $cl = new classifier();
    $text = $current2;

    $result = $cl->classifyText($text);
    if ($result == 'nonstatistika') {
        file_put_contents($file, $current2);
        echo "Rated negative, Thanks for your response!";
    } else {
        echo "Rating failed";
    }
} else {
    echo "Nice..";
}
?>
```

They worked perfectly fine, just how I wanted.
But when I transferred this code into Codeigniter framework, in which I put a controller that has views `file.html`, I found it not working, the function stopped at the `alert(url)`.
I have done like `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>js/jquery.js"></script>` to call the `jquery file`.

I also did this:

```
$("#quote p").load(base_url()+"views/load_hasil_cari/neg.php?url=" + url + "&name=" + name);
```

and this:

```
$file = base_url .'views/load_hasil_cari/cat/nonstatistics/' . $name . '.txt';
```

None of them worked. I clicked the image and all it did is `alert(url)`.

What did I not do? Thanks..

**EDITED:**
This is the controller file:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Retrain extends CI_Controller {

public function Retrain() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->model('home_model');
    $data = $this->home_model->general();
    $data['file']=base_url().'application/views/load_hasil_cari/neg.php';        
    $this->load->view('load_hasil_cari/retrain_view', $data);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add neg.php in Views folder and try to change line

```
$("#quote p").load("neg.php?url="+ url + "&name=" + name);
```

Add  in controller

```
$data['file']=base_url().'application/views/search/cat/nonstatistics/neg.php';
```

And in view change neg.php with

```
<?php echo $file;?>
```

Comment: I did what you told me, now it does nothing at all when I clicked on the image. :(

Comment: Here: `http://localhost/MPSN/application/views/load_hasil_cari/neg.php`. Anyway I did what you wrote in the edited comments, and it gave me this :`Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"
GET http://localhost/mpsn/application/views/load_hasil_cari/neg.php?url=.... 403 (Forbidden)` Now what? :((

Comment: Move neg.php from application and put i root folder public_html and rename $data['file']=base_url().'neg.php';

Answer (score 0):

Try if it works:

1. Put your neg.php at the root of the project folder.
2. Change this line in `neg.php` to `$name = $_GET["name"];`
3. Change this line `$("#quote p").load(base_url()+"views/search/neg.php?url=" + url + "&name=" + name);` to `$("#quote p").load(base_url()+"/neg.php?url=" + url + "&name=" + name);`

Lets do it some other way:
This is the js script

```
function negative(obj) {
   var url = obj.parentNode.valueOf('href');
   var name = obj.parentNode.innerText;
   alert(url);
   $.ajax({
        url     : '<?=base_url()?>/Retrain/load_files',
        type    : 'POST',
        data    : {'url' : url, 'name':name},
        success : function(resp){
            $("#quote p").html(resp);
        },
        error   : function(resp){
            //JSON.stringify(resp);     //uncomment it to alert the error
        }
   });
   //$("#quote p").load("neg.php?url="+ url + "&name=" + name);
}
```

This is a new controller function:

```
function load_files(){       ##controller function which will read the ajax request
    if($this->input->post(null)){
        $this->load->model('home_model');
        echo $this->home_model->load_file();  
    }
}
```

Model function which will return the ajax response:

```
#model function in file home_model.php

function load_file(){
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    $url = $_GET["url"];
    $name = $_GET["name"];

    $file = 'cat/nonstatistics/' . $name . '.txt';
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        include_once 'classifier/classifier.php';
        include_once 'classifier/trainer.php';

        $current = file_get_contents($url);
        $current2 = strip_tags($current);

        $tr = new trainer();//I use PHP text classifier in this
        $arr = array('statistika', 'nonstatistika');
        $tr->makeCategory($arr);
        $cl = new classifier();
        $text = $current2;

        $result = $cl->classifyText($text);
        if ($result == 'nonstatistika') {
            file_put_contents($file, $current2);
            return "Rated negative, Thanks for your response!";
        } else {
            return "Rating failed";
        }
    } else {
        return "Nice..";
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean when I pressed Ctrl+shift+J: Here: `Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" retrain:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) `. Retrain is the controller name.

Comment: Go to the alerted url `alert(url);` directly in a separate tab of your browser and see what response you are getting.

Comment: I went to it and it gave exactly the page. What do I do? I've edited my question, put some controller file there. Will you please take a look? Thanks..

Comment: test and post what errors are you getting now alert the ajax reponse and see your console for errors.

Comment: Now it gives me: `Message: Undefined index: url` and `Message: Undefined index: name`..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33886/discussion-between-niloy-saha-and-safira)