# Fails to load multiple versions of jQuery on the same page

Tags: jquery

I've been desperately trying to load different versions of jQuery, for about 9 hours.
It doesn't work till now..

This is the entire code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>tampilan/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>TAMPILAN/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>TAMPILAN/js/jquery-1.9.1.js.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">       
function negatif(obj) {//onclick function
    var url = obj.parentNode.valueOf('href');
    var nama = obj.parentNode.innerText;
    alert(url);
    jq("#nice").load("retrain/neg.php?url=" + url + "&nama=" + nama);

}
</script>
<p id="nice">nice</p>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabbable">
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="A">
        <p>I'm in Section A.</p>            
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="B">
        <?php ?>
        <p>Howdy, I'm in Section B.</p>
        <?php                       
        $this->load->view('load/search.php');//it has the onclick function
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="C">
        <p>What up girl, this is Section C.</p>            
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript directs to `neg.php`, I post some question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781119/javascript-doesnt-load-php-function-in-codeigniter-but-does-in-pure-php-enviro).

If I remove one of those jQuerys (jquery or jquery 1.9.1), the other works fine. I've tried rearrange the order of the jQuery loads, it didn't work either.

What's the problem here? Thank you..

**EDITED:**

Here that doesn't work (from jquery.js):

```
jq("#nice").load("retrain/neg.php?url=" + url + "&nama=" + nama);
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What's in your JS console when it doesn't work?

Comment: Why would you wish to load two versions of jQuery?

Comment: @Utkanos Sometimes plugins depend on a specific version.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Oh, sorry. Forgot to mention that. I've edited the question, the first jquery that doesn't work.
Utkanos: Because I need both to run the code. The first one (jquery) to run the onclick function. The second one (version 191) for the "section" thing.

Comment: @Safira *How* doesn't it work?

Comment: Dave: It stop just give me `alert(url)`, and when I clicked the image that has onclick `negatif`, it doesn't do anything. 

Dom: Perhaps I accidentally erased it, it has two functions (one with name `positif`, so I didn't enclose it to use smaller space

Comment: In 9 hours of hard work, have you checked your console? Any error?

Comment: @roasted: I've checked the `ctrl+shift+j` several times. It gave nothing on the console tab. :(

@DomDay: It was a typo on the question. I wrote it right in my code.. But still not works. :(

Comment: Trying to load multiple versions of jQuery and still using regular Javascript DOM manipulation. You need to focus here.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: Sorry what do you mean? By all means, will you please elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: well, it looks like it should load. do `alert( jq.fn.jquery )`. If that returns the version number, the problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Taken from the jQuery forum:**

First important thing: when you load your jQuery.x.x.js, it will overwrite the existing `$` and `jQuery` vars... BUT it keeps a backup copy of them (in `_$` and `_jQuery`). 
Calling `.noConflict(true)` you restore the situation as it was before your js inclusion!

`.noConflict()` gives you the running instance (the last loaded), so you can work with your version in this way.

Resuming:

- Original page loads its "jquery.versionX.js"
- `$` and `jQuery` belong to versionX
- You call your "jquery.versionY.js"
- Now `$` and `jQuery` belong to versionY, plus `_$` and `_jQuery` that belongs to versionX
- `var my_jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);`
- now `$` and `jQuery` belong to versionX, `_$` and `_jQuery` are probably `null`, and `my_jQuery` is versionY.

Source: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page